# You’re out of storage space and will soon be unable to send or receive emails until you free up space or purchase additional storage

Tags: gmail, google-drive

I just logged-in to my Gmail and I saw following message:

> You’re out of storage space and will soon be unable to send or receive
>   emails until you free up space or purchase additional storage.

After quick reviewing of my Drive storage, a large portion went to Gmail and Google Photos. I started using Gmail back in 2004 and needless to say I have millions of emails and it's not easy to clean it up.

What's the most efficient way to do clean up my Gmail? (It's not like I can sort by size and see which emails are taking most of space.)

*** UPDATE ***

after using certain label, such as this:

> label:freebsd-questions -label:starred

I hit `Delete` and a minute later I saw this:

> Oops… the system encountered a problem (#793) - Retrying in 1s…

and when I opened another tab to Gmail I saw this:

```
Gmail by Google 

Temporary Error (500)   

We’re sorry, but your Gmail account is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience and suggest trying again in a few minutes. You can view the Apps Status Dashboard for the current status of the service.

If the issue persists, please visit the Gmail Help Center »

Try Again Sign Out


Hide Detailed Technical Info
Numeric Code: 167
```

Any advise?

Comment: Actually, you can filter your Gmail messages by size. This is also an issue that has come up here several times before; give me a few minutes to track down some similar questions.

Comment: See also: [How can I sort emails in Gmail by size?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/how-can-i-sort-emails-in-gmail-by-size)

Comment: See also: [Gmail account is full and can not free space by deleting emails](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40660/gmail-account-is-full-and-can-not-free-space-by-deleting-emails?rq=1)

Comment: See also: [Running Out of Space on GMail, Now What?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22669/running-out-of-space-on-gmail-now-what?lq=1)

Comment: See also: [What to do when Gmail runs out of space?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17733/what-to-do-when-gmail-runs-out-of-space?lq=1)

Comment: (It seems we have a number of duplicates to close.)

Comment: See also: [Google Storage is out of space](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67055/google-storage-is-out-of-space?rq=1)

Comment: Related: [How to effectively manage Google+ storage usage for images and videos?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66047/how-to-effectively-manage-google-storage-usage-for-images-and-videos?rq=1)